# Openstack Kilo dashboard forward

Tags: python, django, openstack-horizon

I've setup the Kilo in LAN, which can't be accessed by the external network. Now, I'd like to do a forwarding to make it be accessed from outside. How to set the **ProxyPass** and **ProxyPassReverse**?

I asked this because for Kilo dashboard, the login decorator will redirect http://host.ip/dashboard --> http://host.ip/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/. And as a result, the access via forwarding will fail.

Can anyone help?

P.S. (apache configuration)

```
# ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xxx.xxx.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
  ## Alias declarations for resources outside the DocumentRoot
  Alias /dashboard/static "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/

  <Directory "/var/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/horizon_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/horizon_access.log" combined 

  ## RedirectMatch rules
  RedirectMatch permanent  ^/$ /dashboard

  ## Server aliases
  ServerAlias 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ServerAlias xxx.xxx.com
  ServerAlias localhost
  WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard group=apache processes=3 threads=10 user=apache
  WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
  WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  That seems like a perfectly reasonable redirect. Can you post some more details of your configuration? Is `host.ip` the address of your proxy? Or the keystone server? How are clients connecting to your proxy?  What ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse configuration have you tried so far?

Comment: My configurations are:  
___ProxyPass / [http://host.ip:80/](http://host.ip:80/)___,  ___ProxyPassReverse / [http://host.ip:80/](http://host.ip:80/)___,  And then, when I access from exernal network using [http://external.domain.name/](http://external.domain.name/), it can successfully accessed the apache root on host.ip(LAN ip of the server with horizon installed), which is now an empty folder. However, to access the dashboard using [http://external.domain.name/dashboard/](http://external.domain.name/dashboard/), I'll got a error: "The requested URL /dashboard was not found on this server"

Comment: When someone asks for additional information it is generally better to update your question, because it is much easier to format things and it makes it more visible to other people who might be able to answer the question.

Comment: When you try to access the dashboard using the external hostname, do you see any evidence of the request in your apache logs (access_log/error_log or equivalent)?  Is your Apache dashboard configuration inside a `<VirtualHost>` block?  If so, can you paste that section of the configuration?

Comment: i updated the vhost configuration in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now fixed. And it works now. The solution is:
add the external domain name http://external.domain.name/ to virtualHost configuration as a serverAlias as shown below:

```
ServerAlias external.domain.name
```